# Functional test for react native on CircleCI

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, circleci

Does exist some functional test framework like selenium(appium) for react native that can be run on circleci continuous integration service

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are several tools for that.

I've personally used http://calaba.sh/ in an Ionic 2 app, I uses Cucumber syntax to write your funcional test, the folks from the Xamarin team are doing a great job. I suggest this one, since many of the test farms services supports for Calabash's scripts.

There is also http://appium.io/, that i think works similar to Calabash but without the cucumber syntax.

Comment: Thank you on answer. I have tried with appium, but test must be run on device or in virtual machine. That is where I found the problem with circleci. I will try calabash.

Comment: Most of them run on actual devices, because they use Selenium internally, and in order to fully make integration test i recommend to test against at least the emulators.